# let rpm %patch not use default --fuzz=0 option

Tags: rpm

I got error as following in el6 machine:

```
Patch #4 (test.patch):
+ /bin/cat /path/to/test.patch
+ /usr/bin/patch -s -p0 --fuzz=0
1 out of 4 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file ***
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file ***
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.YeRtKr (%prep)
```

However, I can apply the patch file with commond as following:

`/usr/bin/patch -s -p0 < /path/to/test.patch`.

I note that rpm set `--fuzz=0` by default.
Is there some way to let rpm not set `--fuzz=0` option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Fedora project wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package):

> Try to ensure that your patch match the context exactly. The default "fuzz" value is "0", requiring matches to be exact. You can work around this by adding `%global _default_patch_fuzz 2` to revert to the value found in older versions of RPM in Fedora, but it is generally recommended to avoid doing this.